# I need to remove a particular tag from JSON object

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON object as follows

```
{
    "mandator":"GB0010001",
    "debitAccount":"81884",
    "creditAccount":"82918",
    "trustedBeneficiary":"false",
    "localCurrencyAmount":35,
    "transactionReference":"omega7.1.1",
    "debitAccountASPSP":"t24",
    "currencyAmount":35,
    "executionDate":"20180102",
    "creditAccountASPSP":"t24",
    "transactionType":"Contactless payment",
    "trustedPSP":"false",
    "jsonErrorResponse":{
        "errorCount":0,
        "errors":[

        ]
    },
    "currency":"USD",
    "company":"GB0010001"
}
```

I need to remove `"jsonErrorResponse":{"errorCount":0,"errors":[]}`, 
I used `JSONobject.remove("jsonErrorResponse").toString()`

But it gave me output as `{"errorCount":0,"errors":[]}` instead of

```
{
    "mandator":"GB0010001",
    "debitAccount":"81884",
    "creditAccount":"82918",
    "trustedBeneficiary":"false",
    "localCurrencyAmount":35,
    "transactionReference":"omega7.1.1",
    "debitAccountASPSP":"t24",
    "currencyAmount":35,
    "executionDate":"20180102",
    "creditAccountASPSP":"t24",
    "transactionType":"Contactless payment",
    "trustedPSP":"false",
    "currency":"USD",
    "company":"GB0010001"
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the javadoc of the `remove` method. And then take a look at your `JSONObject` after you `remove`d the `"jsonErrorResponse"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSONobject.remove("jsonErrorResponse")` returns the thing *that was removed*. You are calling `toString` on the section you have just "deleted".

Simply do not chain the method calls.

```
JSONobject.remove("jsonErrorResponse");
String newJson = JSONobject.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

The remove method most likely returns the object the was removed.
You need to do toString on the object the you removed it from

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working on `JSONobject` you are removing the content from that object.

You need to call `toString()` on the `JSONobject`.

```
String str = "{\"mandator\":\"GB0010001\",\"debitAccount\":\"81884\",\"creditAccount\":\"82918\",\"trustedBeneficiary\":\"false\",\"localCurrencyAmount\":35,\"transactionReference\":\"omega7.1.1\",\"debitAccountASPSP\":\"t24\",\"currencyAmount\":35,\"executionDate\":\"20180102\",\"creditAccountASPSP\":\"t24\",\"transactionType\":\"Contactless payment\",\"trustedPSP\":\"false\",\"jsonErrorResponse\":{\"errorCount\":0,\"errors\":[]},\"currency\":\"USD\",\"company\":\"GB0010001\"}"
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
jsonObject.remove("jsonErrorResponse");
jsonObject.toString();
```